# Designing models in WebAPI with respect to MongoDB

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb, webapi

I'm implementing a model as follow:

There is an entity called ROBOT and any ROBOT may has multiple parameters and any parameters may have settings for telephone number with some options. Here is an example of this model:

```
{
     "Robot": "Test",
     "Parameters: {
          [
               "Name": "Charge",
               "Handling": {
                    [
                         "Min": 4,
                         "Max": 10,
                         "Telephone": "1111111111",
                         "Text": "MyTexT"
                    ],
                    [
                         "Min": 6,
                         "Max": 11,
                         "Telephone": "222222222222",
                         "Text": "Another Text"
                    ]
               }
          ]
     }
}
```

May you please help me how can I design model for this instance with respect to WebAPI and MongoDB?

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to start from inside then go outside, for example you should have a model for you handling property and make it as a class consisting Min, Max, ... . then use handling as a property in the outer section, i.e Partmeter. Then create a class for parameters. When done go in the outer section and put parameters as a property for the main model.